OPC UAのSession.Createが終わらない
OPC UAのSession.Create がエラーを返すわけでもなく永遠に終わらないのですがどのような原因が考えられますか。
プロジェクトのターゲットフレームワークは.NET Framework 4.8、
NuGetのOPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua 1.5.374.54を使用しています。

Session.Create をどのように使用しているかにもよると思われるので、周辺のコードを質問に記載いただければ良いと思います。[編集] から、質問を変更できます。

自己解決しました。Session.Createを含む非同期メソッドを非同期でないメソッド内でWait()を使って呼び出していたのが原因のようです。
